# how to configure piwik-react-router in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matomo, piwiktracker

I have react app that need to use piwik. In jquery events were pushed line this `_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Event category', 'event type']);`
but in react I need to use a separate package https://github.com/joernroeder/piwik-react-router and I try to configure it like in documentation

```
  piwik = PiwikReactRouter({
    url: this.props.piwikUrl,
    siteId: this.props.piwikSiteId,
  });
```

but when I send event like this `this.piwik.push(['trackEvent', 'Event category', type]);`  I get 400 error. Maybe I missed some configs?

Comment: What kind of 400 error do you get?

Comment: `http://pw.sitename.com/piwik.php?e_c=Event%20category&e_a=Event%20name&idsite=3&rec=1&r=809104&h=10&m=55&s=27&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsitename.com%2Fpricing&urlref=http%3A%2F%2Fsitename.com%2F&uid=51896003%20%7C%20Chvfyh%20Bgghgf&_id=3cc0ad0adc0b2a4d&_idts=1529147656&_idvc=5&_idn=0&_refts=0&_viewts=1535610482&send_image=1&cookie=1&res=1255x1039&dimension1=staff&dimension2=Web&gt_ms=212&pv_id=cuARk1 400 (Bad Request)`